# Formato incorreto de data/hora

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

No meu seguinte trecho de código:

```
String horario = evento.getDataOcorrencia().concat(" ").concat(evento.getHoraOcorrencia());
                    horario = horario.replaceAll("/", "-");
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
                    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(horario);
                    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
                    evento.setHorario(timestamp);
```

Minha `String` horario tem o seguinte formato (exemplo):

```
28/03/2017 10:00
```

Eu preciso converter para um timestamp, até aí tudo bem, eu até troco o `/` por `-`. O problema é que ao ser persistido no banco o valor fica assim:

```
2017-03-21 13:35:00
```

Ou seja, é um formato que não gostaria, eu queria que fosse como está no exemplo. Alguém sabe como posso resolver ? A declaração do `JPA` está assim:

```
@Column
@XmlTransient
private Timestamp horario;
```

Comment: Deixe o banco persistir como deseja. Se preocupe com a exibição apenas na hora da exibição. Por sinal, o banco está seguindo o padrão ISO de exibir uma data. Internamente, ele deve estar guardando um número inteiro de muitos bytes. Possivelmente com a quantidade de segundos os milissegundos após epoch

Comment: Nem pra exibir na tela estou conseguindo, como posso fazer ?

Comment: Tá usando `SimpleDateFormat` ou coisa que o valha? Ou tá só no `toString`?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Então não é só uma questão de pegar a String "2017-03-21 13:35:00" obtida do Banco de Dados e transformá-la em uma String "28/03/2017 10:00" para exibir esta última na GUI?